# Hide subdirectories from Media Root (Django)

Tags: django, apache, static, media

I'm serving static media content on the same server as my Django app. I'm doing so through an apache2 config file which Alias-es my media directory.

It works in that the server serves the media directory as static content and the Django app through a WSGI.

The problem is that, when a user goes to my media url (www.mysite/media/) they can view all of my static content directories. I don't want that.

What can I do about this?

Thanks, 
Brendan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either disable directory listings ([`Options`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options)) or add empty `index.html` files.

Comment: i think the correct option is a `Options -Indexes` (or remove the `Indexes` from the line. In my server it is inside <directory></directory>

Comment: I've decided to go with adding an index.html, since the Options solution produces an unattractive 403 response.  Thanks guys

Comment: U need to add index.html in subfolders as well, else subfolders will still show directory listings